# Shopping cart Problem with Angular - Wrong response in View

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

my Onlineshop should display the quantity of different products in my shoppingcart. In Firebase my shoppingcard exists and also the products are saved in the existing cart but in my Browser the quantity is always 0. In the getQuantity() in product-card.component.ts I can´t reach the else condition. 
Everything works fine and there are no Errors or problems with this code. By the way I´m a beginner so don´t blame me pls :-)
Maybe there is a way to use the cartId somehow?

My Code:

product-card.component.ts:

```
import { Product } from './../models/product';
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ShoppingCartService } from '../shopping-cart.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'product-card',
  templateUrl: './product-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-card.component.css']
})
export class ProductCardComponent {
  @Input('product') product: Product
  @Input('show-actions') showActions = true;
  @Input('shopping-cart') shoppingCart;
  shoppingCartService: ShoppingCartService;


  constructor(private cartService: ShoppingCartService) {

  }

  addToCart(product: Product) {
    this.cartService.addToCart(product);
  }

  getQuantity() {
    if (!this.shoppingCart) {
      console.log("Shopping Cart: " + this.shoppingCart)
      return 0; // 0 is the Response in Browserterminal
    } else {
      let item = this.shoppingCart.items[this.product.key];
      console.log(this.shoppingCart)
      return item ? item.quantity : 0;
    }
  }
}
```

shopping-cart.service.ts:

```
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from './models/product';
import { take, first } from 'rxjs/operators';



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ShoppingCartService {


  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {   }


  private create() {
    return this.db.list('/shopping-carts').push({
       dateCreated: new Date().getTime()
     });
   }


   async getCart(){
     let cartId = await this.getOrCreateCartId();
     console.log("Von getCart() übergebene cartId = "+cartId);
    return this.db.object('/shopping-carts' + cartId);
  }

  private getItem(cartId:string, productId:string){
    console.log("von getItem() übergebene cartId: "+cartId+ " und productId: "+productId);
 return this.db.object('/shopping-carts/' +cartId+ '/items/' + productId);
  }

  private async getOrCreateCartId() : Promise <string> {
    let cartId = localStorage.getItem('cartId');
    if (cartId) {
      return cartId
    }else{
    let result = await this.create();
    localStorage.setItem('cartId', result.key);
    console.log("keine cartID vorhanden");
    return result.key;
  }
}

//cart = Promise because of the async in getOrCreateCart()
  async addToCart(product:Product){
    let cartId = await this.getOrCreateCartId();
    let item$ = this.getItem (cartId, product.key);
   item$.valueChanges().pipe(take(1)).subscribe((item:any) => {
  if (item){ item$.update({ quantity : item.quantity +1 })
  }else{
  item$.set({ product: product, quantity: 1}); 
}
});
  }
}
```

products.component.ts:

```
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy  {

  products: Product[] = [];
  filteredProducts: Product[] = [];
 category: string;
 products$: Observable<any>;
 cart:any;
 subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(
     route: ActivatedRoute,
     productService: ProductService,
     private shoppingCartService: ShoppingCartService) {

 productService.getAll()
   .subscribe (products => { 
  console.log(products); this.products = products;
  route.queryParamMap;
   })
  route.queryParamMap.subscribe(params => {
    this.category = params.get('category');
    this.filteredProducts = (this.category) ? 
     this.products.filter(p => p.category === this.category) : 
    this.products;
  });

}

    async ngOnInit(){
   this.subscription = (await this.shoppingCartService.getCart()).valueChanges()
   .subscribe(cart => {
     console.log("cart = "+cart); //mit valueChanges() ist cart=null
     return this.cart = cart;
   });
    }


    ngOnDestroy(){
this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
```

product-card.component.html:

```
...
<div class="col text-center">
            {{ getQuantity() }} in cart
           </div>
...
```

products.component.html:

```
...
<div class="col">
         <product-card [product] = "p" [shopping-cart] = "cart"></product-card>
      </div>
...
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the `shoppingCart` variable is supposed to be, but if it's an array, you might want to check if it's empty : `!shoppingCart.length`, rather than just checking if it's set : `!shoppingCart || !shoppingCart.length`

Comment: Missing / in getCart()?  return this.db.object('/shopping-carts/' + cartId);

Comment: @Doguita you are right... it just was a typo. Thank you all for your answers! I appreciate it.